# Why my code does not write the results to the file?

Tags: c, file

I am writing a code that reads the characters from a file, and then if one of these characters is 'A' it should be changed to 'Z', after these changes are made it should write it back to the file (not append, but write), but whenever I open the file after running the code or it is empty, corrupted, or the compiler shouts at me (since I tried correcting it by making some changes, here is the code I have so far:

```
int main(){
    char variable1[2000000];
    FILE *filePointer1;
    FILE *filePointer2;
    int counter;
    int exact_char_numb;

    filePointer1 = fopen("File.txt", "r");
    filePointer2 = fopen("File.txt", "w");
    fread(variable1,2000000,sizeof(char), filePointer1);

    for(counter = 0; counter<= 2000000 ; counter ++){
        if(variable1[counter] == 'A'){
            variable1[counter] = 'Z';
        }
        if(variable1[counter] == '+'){
            exact_char_numb = counter; // I am using '+' to mark the end of
        }                              // the file (for now)
    }

    fwrite(variable1,sizeof(char),exact_char_numb,filePointer2);

    printf("%s\n", variable1);
    printf("%d\n", exact_char_numb);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm having quite a hard time reading this code, can you format it to make it more clear for us to answer?

Comment: Ok, I will see what I can do (im a newbie to programing)

Comment: Looks like you never call fclose() on your file handles; you need to do that when you’re done using them, or the in-memory buffers won’t get flushed to disk.

Comment: You should check what `fread` `return`s instead of assuming `2000000`: `counter<= 2000000`.

Comment: Also, if you're not embedded, check man of `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

In this call:

```
fwrite(variable1,sizeof(char),exact_char_numb,filePointer2);
```

the variable `exact_char_numb` is likely equal to zero, so you don't get any output. You should turn on all warnings and the compiler will complain to you about the variables that can be used without initializing them first.

Answer (score 0):

> "*but whenever I open the file after running the code or it is empty, corrupted, or the compiler shouts at me...*"

You should check whether the opening of the streams to `file.txt` were successful by checking the returned pointers for a null pointer before doing any operations with the streams:

```
if (!(filePointer1 = fopen("File.txt", "r")))
{
    fputs("Error occurred at opening file to read!", stderr);
    exit(1);
}

if (!(filePointer2 = fopen("File.txt", "w")))
{
    fputs("Error occurred at opening file to write!\n", stderr);
    exit(1);    
}
```

---

Furthermore, you don´t need to do have two pointers to two different streams. Use `r+` mode:

```
if (!(filePointer = fopen("File.txt", "r+")))
{
    fputs("Error occurred at opening file!", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```